# web.config rewrite rule to update the path and query string value

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a requirement to rediect the URL from https:/my.original.domain.com/**quickLinks/forms/formdetail**?ID={**XXXX**}&FormTemplateID={**YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY**}&FormItemID={**ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ**}

to

https:/my.original.domain.com/**services/forms/formdetail**?ID={**AAAA**}&FormTemplateID={**BBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBB**}&FormItemID={**CCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC**}

The catch here is that we only have to change the pieces which are mentioned in **bold**. We need the rewrite URL for this to work in web.config for the dot net application. We don't have to write any code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below rule that worked for me:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Query string and path update" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^quickLinks/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/serv-support-and-resources/{R:1}/{R:2}?id=1234&amp;FormTemplateID=%7B985861A2-58B4-4082-B95E-EF19699FC850%7D&amp;FormItemID=%7BFD8DE5D7-4078-4CD8-B4E7-A5B4EFF7F852%7D" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The `url="^quickLinks/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)` matches the url if starts with `quickLinks`, ignoring the case, then it simply redirects to my choice's url and query string which is mentioned in the `url` attribute of the `<action>` tag.

Here, `{R:1}` and `{R:2}` are as `quickLinks/{R:1}/{R:2}`